# C# mock local reference variable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Is there any way to mock out a MyObject obj without refactoring anything?

```
public class BadClass{

   public int Process(){
      MyObject obj=new MyObject();
      return obj.doSomething(); 
   }

}
```

Comment: Short answer - no.

Comment: Microsoft fakes could

Comment: @404 searching the internet all day, there is not a single example/sample anything. Can you share a post if you know one? Thanks

Comment: @Imran here's a link with a good explanation to get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019#get-started-with-shims . What you basically want is create a `ShimsContext` in your unit test and change the behaviour of the `MyObject` class. e.g. `ShimMyObject.AllInstances.doSomething = () { //new behaviour }`

Comment: @404 thanks, worked. Can you add an answer so that I can mark it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually does the trick, but interestingly seems like it is only me using msfakes. When it comes to java on such a thing, there are hundereds of high quality articles, but in c# there is only one in MS website showing how to mock a static date.

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private BadClass badClass=new BadClass();

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                SampleCCProject.Fakes.ShimMyObject.AllInstances.doSomething =
                   @class =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                        return 9;
                    };

                Assert.AreEqual(badClass.Process(), 9);
            }
        }
    }
```